# I accidentally deleted the directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-22-generic. How can I recover it?

Tags: kernel, filesystem, 21.04

I am on Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) and I accidentally deleted the `5.11.0-22-generic` directory in directory `/lib/modules`.

How can I recover or reinstall it?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt install linux-image-generic` ?

Comment: @ArturMeinild that will not help.That package is installed, and `apt install` will just report that.

Comment: My bad, I actually also meant to issue a reinstall.

Comment: This is exactly why it requires root rights to remove those files... Are you sure this is the only thing that is needing fixing?

Comment: @PeterMortensen more importantly, I guess, it contains directories with all the drivers built for that kernel... But there is a conflict between the title of the question and the body - `linux-image-generic` is a meta package and so it provides no files - it only exists for package management reasons. I am going to edit the title and make it match the body, since the answer is about that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Keep out of your system files in the first place. It is hard to understand how one can "accidentally" delete that directory. Forgive this rant, but it has to get out of my way.

Presumably, `5.11.0-22` is not the kernel you are currently running. Otherwise, you would not be able to restart.

You can reinstall that kernel image with the command

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-5.11.0-22-generic linux-modules-5.11.0-22-generic linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-22-generic
```

The `--reinstall` option should indicate `apt` to effectively redownload and reinstall the package. That should bring back in any missing files.